# How To Get Distinct Lists?

Tags: c#, distinct

With the lists below, how can I get the distinct lists from the lists below without doing a full brute-force comparison?  In the example, list2 and list3 are identical, so I would only want list1 and list2.

```
var list1 = new List<int>{1,2,3,4,5};
var list2 = new List<int>{2,3};
var list3 = new List<int>{3,2};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the lists with a collection of `HashSet`s.

You can then write

```
hashSets.Distinct(HashSet<int>.CreateSetComparer())
```

Comment: Doesn't this assume he's fine with not allowing duplicate entries? For the operation its alright to not have duplicates, but whats to say that duplicate entries aren't valid in some other usage?

Comment: @FlyingStreudel: Correct.  If he's ignoring order, it's usually safe to assume that he doesn't want duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** Use List<>.Sort + IEnumerable's .Any and .SequenceEqual

```
public static List<List<int>> Test1(List<int>[] lists)
{
    var result = new List<List<int>>();
    foreach(var list in lists)
    {
        list.Sort();
        if(!result.Any(elm => elm.SequenceEqual(list)))
            result.Add(list);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Here's a simple benchmark/test showing the HashSet method and the pre-.Sort .Any .SequenceEqual method. **edit** http://ideone.com/x3CJ8I of course ideone probably isn't the best benchmarking platform so feel free to run it on your own machine.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Diagnostics;

public class Demo
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int tries = 100;
        int count = 50;
        int size = 1000;
        Random rnd = new Random();
        List<int>[] list;
        Stopwatch sw;

        sw = new Stopwatch();
        for(int x=0; x<tries; x++)
        {
            list = new List<int>[count];
            for(int y=0; y<count; y++)
            {
                list[y] = new List<int>();
                for(int z=0; z<size; z++)
                {
                    int n = rnd.Next();
                    list[y].Add(n);
                }
                if((y % 5) == 0 && y > 0)
                { // make repeated lists for the uniqueness check
                    list[y-1] = new List<int>(list[y]);
                    list[y-1].Reverse();
                }
            }
            sw.Start();
            Test1(list);
            sw.Stop();
        }
        Console.WriteLine( sw.Elapsed.ToString() );

        sw = new Stopwatch();
        for(int x=0; x<tries; x++)
        {
            list = new List<int>[count];
            for(int y=0; y<count; y++)
            {
                list[y] = new List<int>();
                for(int z=0; z<size; z++)
                {
                    int n = rnd.Next();
                    list[y].Add(n);
                }
                if((y % 5) == 0 && y > 0)
                { // make repeated lists for the uniqueness check
                    list[y-1] = new List<int>(list[y]);
                    list[y-1].Reverse();
                }
            }
            sw.Start();
            Test2(list);
            sw.Stop();
        }
        Console.WriteLine( sw.Elapsed.ToString() );
    }
    public static List<List<int>> Test1(List<int>[] lists)
    {
        var result = new List<List<int>>();
        foreach(var list in lists)
        {
            list.Sort();
            if(!result.Any(elm => elm.SequenceEqual(list)))
                result.Add(list);
        }
        return result;
    }
    public static List<HashSet<int>> Test2(List<int>[] lists)
    {
        var result = new List<HashSet<int>>();
        foreach(var list in lists)
        {
            result.Add(new HashSet<int>(list));
        }
        result = result.Distinct(HashSet<int>.CreateSetComparer()).ToList();
        return result;
    }
}
```

**EDIT** I had time to modify the test, turns out the overhead of creating HashSets + .Distinct is **edit** EVERY SIMILAR to that of .Sort + .Any + .SequenceEqual. http://ideone.com/x3CJ8I

Comment: Note that this is noticeably less performant than a hash-based solution.

Comment: @Servy - I don't know how noticeable the performance would be. Perhaps you can benchmark it. Also, just because a solution may have less lines of code doesn't always guarantee it will be faster.

Comment: What's your basis for assuming that I was using lines of code as a benchmark?  I was not.  Sorting is not a particularly cheap operation, at least in comparison to what's going on in a hash-based solution in terms of the asymptotic complexity of the algorithm being used.  Your first solution is particularly bad, as you end up sorting each of the lists quite a few different times.

Comment: @Servy - Here's a simple test http://ideone.com/gDBrrS doesn't seem to show much of an advantage at all. Sorting small lists integer lists doesn't seem to bother .NET. Perhaps you can modify the simple test to demonstrate your point?

Comment: Sure sorting a list of size 2 is going to be fast...you'd need to have a non-trivially sized data set to do a meaningful performance test.  Now if you sort several dozen lists with a few hundred items each (which is actually a rather small amount of data) you can start to get an idea of what the performance differences might be.  If you want to look at a larger amount of data you could go with lists with several thousand or tens of thousands of lines, which a more modest amount of data.

Comment: @Servy - I'm basing it off the OP's question. There's no hint that he needs non-trivially sized data sets. Perhaps you can ask him to clarify his use case, so assumptions aren't necessary? Also, the complexity of algorithms isn't always relevant in the real world, academically however, I'd likely choose the HashSet answer.

Comment: The OP provided some sample data to give us an idea of what's going on.  That doesn't mean it's the only data that the answer needs to work on.  If it did, then the best answer would be to hard code the solution of using list 1 and 2.  A sample input using lots and lots of data would also be impractical and doesn't easily demonstrate the intended algorithm, so seeing small sample input doesn't mean the "real" data is always as small.  Finally, I'm not exclusively saying this answer shouldn't be used because of performance reasons, that's just one point against it.

Comment: @Servy - http://ideone.com/y6juZo Turns out I can't find a case where the HashSet solution would actually be faster. As you scale up the number of and length of the lists the overhead from creating a HashSet and using IEnumerable.Distinct grows faster than my solution. Guess you were wrong, going to change your vote?

Comment: Sorry, but no.  You're creating the list once at the start and then re-using all of those lists for each of the 100 tests.  The first time you run your code it mutates the lists, sorting them all.  For each of the other 99 tests the data is already sorted, which is the best case for the sorting algorithm that is being used.

Comment: The test that I just ran in which I modified your code to use a fresh array of lists for each of your tests resulted in your solution being 50% slower than the second.  Oh, side note, you shouldn't use `DateTime.Now` for performance benchmarks, you should use `StopWatch` instead, it's dramatically more precise.  Another point worth mentioning is that in your test virtually none of the lists will ever actually be equal.  Your test actually takes a lot less time when it can quickly determine that lists aren't a match, so the same or similar lists take longer to test.

Comment: @Servy - Great! http://ideone.com/x3CJ8I The gears are still turning the latest revision has gotten the HashSet to about 0.9x the speed of the pre-sorting (not a trouncing, but a win non-the-less). I naively thought ideone would frown upon using System.Diagnostics namespace, but it turns out its whitelisting is quite good. With regards to equal lists the modulus code is used to generate a repeats.

Comment: You still haven't addressed the point I most recently made.  All of the lists are radically different in their content, thus suiting your solution rather significantly.  If you use `random.Next(50)` (or even 1000) instead of `Next()` in both places note the *dramatic* difference.  Also note how the difference increases (as a percentage) as the size  of the lists increase, due to the improved asymptotic complexity.

Comment: @Servy - we're alreayd constraining the list values to positive integers with rnd.Next() there's no hint that constraining them further would even be in scope. Changing the parameters like that we could always just start with sorted lists and hashset's and see if .Any .SequenceEqual or .Distinct is faster. Depending on the poetic license taken with the OP's vague question, virtually any result could be possible.

Comment: So the point is that the specifics of the data *do* matter.  You shouldn't just use one configuration and then call it a day.  You need to analyze what kinds of paths are preferable and undesirable for each algorithm and perf test them with each.  Then you can attempt to determine which of the tests will be most representitive of your data.  For example, if you find that under conditions X and Y, algorithm A is better, but under conditions Z they're about the same, then you'd use algorithm A because it's either the same or better, even though it's not *always* better.

Comment: @@Servy - But we've definitely beaten the dead horse, so I'm satisfied to leave at SLaks victory with an asterisk noting results vary greatly depending on input and the specific use-case.

Answer (score -1):

You could also concat the three lists and then do a .Distinct()

```
list<int> newList = list1.Concat(list2.Concat(list3)).Distinct();
```

Comment: Apparently the OP wants a list of lists "List<List<int>>" as a result. The question is a bit difficult to read.